# Azure Cognitive Search, how to configure analyzer to support "startsWith"?

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have a field in Azure Cognitive Search that has special characters in it.
they look like this: some_id: 'SOME*STUFF*123'
I'm trying to have a "startsWith" query, but that doesnt return anything as soon as the regex tries to match anything that goes farther than the \*
After a bit google I found out its the Analyzer, possibly breaking apart strings at '*'
So I changed the Analyzer to "keyword", as I read multiple times its the Analyzer you are supposed to use for this.

the new config looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "some_id",
 "type": "Edm.String",
 "facetable": false,
 "filterable": true,
 "key": false,
 "retrievable": true,
 "searchable": true,
 "sortable": true,
 "analyzer": "keyword",
 "indexAnalyzer": null,
 "searchAnalyzer": null,
 "synonymMaps": [],
 "fields": []
 },
```

my request look like this:

```
{
    "count": true,
    "skip": 0,
    "top": 5,
    "searchMode": "any",
    "queryType": "full",
    "search": "some_id:/SO(.*)/" // SOME\\*S(.*) also doesnt work
}
```

I get zero matches.

With the Standart analyzer I started going no matches as soon as I had a \\* in my regex (I escaped them with \\)

*Clarification on Requirements*:
I can not change any data, the values (including the \*) can not be changed. I'm trying to have the whole field matched as a single token and for me to run startsWith on.

For example this regex: `/SOME\\*ST(.*)/` is supposed to literally return entries that fully match the regex. No magic with seperators or tokens, simply the whole value as a single token that I can run startsWith on.
What I'm trying to say is, take for example JavaScript, I want the exact same results you would get from string.startsWith(value).

I'm guessing there is either something wrong with my config, or with my requests, can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to check starts with for text coming after `some_id:` ?

Comment: what do you mean?
some_id is the field name and SOME\*STUFF\*123 is the format of most values in the index

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should work with a different separator. For example:

```
Field1 (FROM) | Field2 (TO)

SOME*STUFF*123  | SOME||STUFF||123
```

Then use a custom analyzer to break terms every ||. Aditionally, you can also work with tokenizer and specify it to do it every 3 chars.

Samples:

```
SOM
OME
STU
TUF
UFF
123
```

Then search using:

SOM*

and it should return the data you're looking for. It would be better if you could provide more details about your content and give us samples, but this answer should point you to the result you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, I updated the Post. You are right, I should have clarified, I cannot change any data, I simply need the whole value as a single token so I can run anything that would work similarly to startsWith. I know this is a far stretch, but basically exactly the same results you would get with this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith.

Comment: Even if you can't change the data, you can create a separate property that contains the same data with different separators. E.g. some_id: 'SOME*STUFF*123' and some_id2: 'SOME||STUFF||123'. You then search against some_id2, but you can render some_id in your frontend so it appears that no data has changed.

Comment: I dont get it, how would that fix my problem? I simply want startsWith, while treating special characters like normal characters. no splitting, nothing, just a startsWith on the entire field

Comment: take a look on tokenizer and custom analyzers, it will solve you need. Even with the support of regex, it won't be performatic, the way I'm recommending you solve your need.